# How do I model time series data that contains a unique ID and a constant time step?

Tags: python, time-series, predictive-modeling, lstm

My data currently looks like this (after processing, 15 mins timesteps):

```
date                ID     count
2017-06-01 00:00:00 1      4208 
2017-06-01 00:00:00 2      3993 
2017-06-01 00:15:00 1      3740 
2017-06-01 00:15:00 2      3482 
...
```

I want to predict the count for a given ID in a given timestep (eg: count for ID 1 at 20:00:00-20:15:00 interval) using the past data. I believe that it can be modelled using LSTM since we are using a time sequence, but I'm unsure on how to format the inputs/outputs for it. I would appreciate if someone could share any related work or an overview of how to model such a problem.

Comment: Are ID 1 and 2 the only IDs in the dataset?

Comment: Can you add more information about the domain and any possible added data? Why for example is this not a simple calculus problem (e.g. assuming a constant rate of change over time). What kind of pre-analysis have you done?

Comment: @N.Kiefer there are more IDs but I have taken 2 for simplicity.

Comment: @fnguyen the problem is about forecasting user demand in an area over fixed time steps of 15 mins. The rate of change is not fixed and changes over the entire duration of the data I have. Unfortunately, I can’t share the specifics of the data and actual samples due to confidentiality issues